# iFrame disappears on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

A friend of mine created a simple web site using iWeb and added an iFrame to one of the pages. iWeb seems to be loading iFrames through a series of Javascript libraries and CSS files (quite strange). But whenever I look at this page on IE, the iFrame disappears after a few seconds: http://bit.ly/fD7QGD

Does anyone know what could be causing this buggy behavior on IE?

Thanks,
Ralph

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried it on Firefox, Chrome and IE and waited more than 1 minutes. It didn't disappear.
Maybe there's a problem with your browser or it was a temporary bug.